# Get attribute without iteration

Tags: c#, attributes, properties, custom-attributes

Is it possible to read custom attribute value without iterating through all list of attributes? I use code below to read attribute value `attributeData.IncludeResult` but I think should easy more optimal way to do that without using `foreach` and iteration.

```
foreach (var customAttributeData in
         propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebClientAttribute), false))
{
    var attributeData = (WebClientAttribute)customAttributeData;
    myData = attributeData.IncludeResult
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
WebClientAttribute attrib = (WebClientAttribute)
    Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propertyInfo, typeof(WebClientAttribute));
```